# Vue.js When input elements are present, strange error appears in console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application

**AT FIRST:**

Error in event handler:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Password') at
> c.D
> (chrome-extension://deakbjemijlmlcehdgejmdpekkceodmk/data/content_script.js:49:270)

This happens in any vanilla vue.js project.
You can take the following links as reference or setup your own project:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/ (Vue 2)

https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/checkboxes (Vue 3)

I'm not able to go behind this problem, and I didn't find any similar occurrences in others.

Thank you in advance.

**MODIFIED:**

For further explanation:

the project is created with vue-cli like this:
`vue create example`

I just modified the HelloWorld component like this:

```
<template>
    <input type="text" v-model="example">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Foo",
  data:()=>({
    example:''
  })
};
</script>
```

This is the only thing actually in my html, when serving the app I get this error:

> Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'Password')
> at c.D (chrome-extension://deakbjemijlmlcehdgejmdpekkceodmk/data/content_script.js:49:270)
> at c.o (chrome-extension://deakbjemijlmlcehdgejmdpekkceodmk/data/content_script.js:52:234)
> at c.register (chrome-extension://deakbjemijlmlcehdgejmdpekkceodmk/data/content_script.js:53:395)
> at Ld (chrome-extension://deakbjemijlmlcehdgejmdpekkceodmk/data/content_script.js:180:13)
> at od (chrome-extension://deakbjemijlmlcehdgejmdpekkceodmk/data/content_script.js:183:105)

The error doesn't affect the app at any point, you can work with it without any further issues, but for any input, you have in the app you get this error in the console.

**SOLVED**

A specific extension tool in chrome caused this error, I could not disable it because it was a requirement.

The extension causing this error was Harmony Web protection, as I said for my corporation this tool is required and pre-installed on the devices.

More information on the extension:
https://www.checkpoint.com/harmony/browse/

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Password')" normally tells you that ```Password``` is not defined in your data. So please double check in your data if ```Password``` is defined as a String or something else, than it should work.

Comment: Why should I have Password defined in my data when I'm not using credentials or password for anything, why would the script ask for an unexisting password. I told in the Issue, clean project, just a normal html input gives the same error out, not even needing a form.

Comment: Could you please provide some code in here? Than it will be easier to solve this.

Comment: Just modified the description for you, check it out

Comment: Looks that there is an extension installed in your browser which causing of this error.

Comment: Hi @DanielRequejo, welcome to SO, as you solved I think is better if you write an answer in the section to answer questions with more details and this can help others to find an answer if they have a similar issue.

Comment: Done, ty for the advice Jose

Answer (score -1):

chrome-extension://kbjemijlmlcehdgejmdpekkceodmklkdjlkjd/data/content_script.js:49:270

This is happening in the React.js also because Harmony extension
[took screen shot of the Chrome-extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zLKF.png)

problem is : If you add a input field in reactJs/angular/vueJs, harmony reads the input field value and React shouts it out loud. rest in peace security

adding the harmony link https://www.checkpoint.com/harmony/browse/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30839086)

Comment: I added the screenshot of harmony extension brother not some link, this error occurs only with company laptops with harmony extension in the browsers. I hope u understand this. I'm disappointed with the  your -ve one.  If you add a input field in the reactJs/angular/vueJs, harmony reads the input value and react shouts it out loud. rest in peace security